# Upgrading HTC Wildfire S to Jelly Bean

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean

How can I upgrade my wildfire s to jellybean? Help anyone?
What are the risks? I tried to look up on google but couldn't find anything usefull..HELP!

Answer (score 0):

HTC has dropped upgrade support for the Wildfire S. If you want to have Jelly Bean you have to :

## **1. Unlock the bootloader**

This is done by going to the [htcdev](http://www.htcdev.com/bootloader/) website and select your device on the dropdown to the  right. All the procedure is described on the site, but be warned that by doing this, you void your device's garranty. (though it can be relocked, but a relocked device is easily identified by a "** RELOCKED **" mention on the bootloader).

## **2. Root your device**

A user on xda-developers forum has developed a "One click root" program. You can download it on the [original thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1678421), run it and follow the instructions.

## **3. Install a custom rom**

There are many different CyanogenMod 10.1 rom (the Wildfire S community seems pretty fragmented to me...), but one I recommend is the one by the [Owl Project](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2283549). Simply download the zip file, put it in the root of your sdcard. Power off your device, power it on while holding the volume down button, choose `install zip from sdcard` and pick the downloaded zip file. If you are not satisfied, you can choose another one from the [Wildfire S development section](http://forum.xda-developers.com/forumdisplay.php?f=1038)

***BUT !*** Be warned that all of these procedure may or may not harm your device and nobody could be held responsible for this. (though if you follow the instructions, there is a very minimal chance of bricking your device)